# how to append to a file using scala/breeze library

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I wish to write to a file the output row of result matrix (produced in iterations) so that I can support checkpointing.

I figured we can use the `csvwrite` command to write the entire matrix to a file but how can I append to a file?

I am looking for something like below:

```
breeze.linalg.csvwrite(new File("small.txt"),myMatrix(currRow,::).t.asDenseMatrix)
```

However the above command overwrites the file each time the command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in to Breeze. (Contributions welcome!)

you can use breeze.io.CSVWriter.write directly if you would like.